# what is the use of CrudRepository in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
@RepositoryRestResource

public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> 
{
public List<Student> findById(long id);

//@Query("select s from Student s where s.age <= ?")
public List<Student> findByAgeLessThanEqual (long age);
}
```

what does `<Student, long>` mean in the `CrudRepository<Student, long>` and what are the various parameters that can be passed to cruderepository.

Comment: Have you read the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories ? It's all there.

Comment: thanks for the link @koe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea of `CrudRepository` is to give you opportunity to use main operations with data without creating your own implementation. You just create needed methods and for most simple cases Spring will create implementation for you (if you use right naming convention for your methods).

First parameter (`Student` in your case) is a type of entity with which current Repository is working, second parameter (`Long` in your case) is a type of `Id` in this entity.

Answer (score 1):

CrudRepository provides methods for the CRUD operations. This interface extends the Repository interface. If you are extending the CrudRepository, there is no need for implementing your own methods.

If do not want data from custom parameter, you have to write custom query for it.

you can use only that parameters which is their in your CrudRepository.